# Select two values from a combobox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have the following SP :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[selectService]
as
begin
     select cl_mt,cl_cl_id,cl_description from REF_CLIENT_TABLE
end
```

and i'm using it to fill my combobox :

```
        With service_combo
        .DataSource = serviceTable
        .DisplayMember = "cl_description"
        .ValueMember = "cl_mt"
        .SelectedIndex = 0
        .SelectedValue = serviceTable.Rows("cl_mt")
    End With
```

is there a way by any chance to be able to select 2 values? because i need to select the "cl_mt" and the "cl_id"

Comment: I think you should opt for any other control as combobox is intended for single selection only.

Comment: like what? what do you suggest?

Comment: so, do you want to show 2 selection criteria or selection of 2 values from single combobox?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to get `cl_mt` from `cl_id` anyway? I assume `cl_id` is unique. Or are you trying to avoid database visits?

Comment: i need to select 2 values from a single text in combobox

Comment: @AdrianWragg i'm trying to avoid database visit ..

Comment: The combobox is a one-column, single-selection control. If you want multiple columns, you should better use a different control (e.g., datagrid, listbox, listview, etc.); if you want one column but multiple selections, you might prefer to choose a checkedListBox (which also accepts multiple columns). Even you might write two values in the same Combobox line ("value1 -- value2"). There are plenty of options to get what you want. Can you please be more precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding an expression-based column to your original table:

```
  serviceTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("binding", GetType(String),
                                                    "cl_mt + '|' + cl_id"))

  With service_combo
      .DataSource = serviceTable
      .DisplayMember = "cl_description"
      .ValueMember = "binding"
      ...
  End With
```

When you now query `service_combo.SelectedValue`, you will get a value returned in the form `1|2`; this will be your `cl_mt` field followed by your `cl_id` field.

Comment: when i'm binding the two fields the datatable is being returned empty although it had data before adding the new column